# delete or rename a file with \r as the file name

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I have a pesky little file whose name appears to be single character, and that character is a `\r`

How can I delete this?

This is what I get with `ls -bl`:

```
-rw-rwxr--+   1 root             snapplewriters        0 Aug 29  2011 \r
```

`ls -l` just display it "?"

Comment: How did you even end up with a file named like that?

Answer (score 16):

Us `ls -li` to get the inode number for the file (first column), then use `find` to delete it (assuming inode is 12345):

`find . -inum 12345 -exec rm -i {} \;`

Comment: Thank you - this is extremely helpful - I felt like there must be some kind of unequivocal system reference to the file but couldn't find it (quickly anyway).

Comment: Depending on the version of `find` installed, you could also do `find . -inum 12345 -delete`

Comment: For me, the more version-agnostic it is, the better. But good suggestion none-the-less. :)

Answer (score 14):

use ANSI-C quoting: `rm $'\r'`

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Answer (score 5):

I would personally reach for Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> '\r' in os.listdir('.')
True
>>> os.unlink('\r')
```

But you can also do this from the shell if you understand escape characters.

```
$ ls -b $'\r'
\r
$ rm -vi $'\r'
rm: remove regular empty file ‘\r’? y
removed ‘\r’
```

Comment: I guess you also have a sledgehammer in your kitchen? Just in case you need to crack a nut? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another quick way to remove a file called `<carriage return>` if you're using the Bash shell is:

```
$ rm <control-v><control-m>
```

Answer (score 2):

Single-character file names are unusual, and if you don't have any other such files in your directory, you can try this:

```
rm ?
```

I'm too lazy to learn or look up how to quote strange characters, so I've used variants of this a number of times when I was stuck with files with difficult names.

Comment: -1 This matches *all* files with a single character name - See "Pathname Expansion" in `man bash`. Try `touch a b c d $'\r'; rm ?`

Comment: @l0b0: Yes? As I wrote, single-character file names are unusual. It is fairly likely that there are no other such files in the directory, and in that case, this works. Otherwise "rm -i ?" can be used.