# Need to delete a file I accidentally labeled in quotes in Linux

Tags: linux, rm

I have a file which I wrote and not thinking put the actual filename in single quotes like this:

```
'filename'
```

When I try to remove it using `rm -f 'filename'` it does not recognize that it is there I get the error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'filename'. No such file or directory.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete a file with a weird name](http://superuser.com/questions/451979/how-to-delete-a-file-with-a-weird-name), http://superuser.com/questions/229851/how-to-delete-file-with-this-name-on-linux-q, http://superuser.com/questions/540704/undeletable-file-in-redhat-linux, http://superuser.com/questions/408121/delete-or-rename-a-file-with-r-as-the-file-name

Answer (score 10):

Quote the quotes.

```
rm "'filename'"
```

Comment: If, like me you have quotes and non-ascii characters, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146768/3387223

Answer (score 3):

Another option (in addition to [@IgnacioVasquezAbrams's answer](https://superuser.com/a/646644/167207)) is to escape the <kbd>'</kbd>

```
rm \'filename\'
```

[image]